How to style td on server side datable
I have my below code for server side processing using datatable and it is working well.
Am getting the data to my html from my server side script and everything is ok
My problem is: How can I style <td> for the returned data, like:
<td><a href=""> returned data column 4 value goes here </a></td>
<td><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i> returned data column 2 value goes here</td>

output from the server side script
{
  "draw": "iTotalRecords",
  "1": null,
  "data": [
    [
      "456777",
      "Jane",
      "USA",
      "Link",
      1],
  ]
}

My html looks like this
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <title>DataTables</title>

        <!-- DataTables CSS library -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- DataTables JS library -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="datable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>                    
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#datable").dataTable({
               "processing": true,
               "serverSide": true,
               "ajax": {
               "url": "jjj.php",
               "type": "POST",
               "dataType":"json"
              },
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>


Did you look at the how to style datatables documentation?

Why do you even need to do this with jQuery? Why can't you just use CSS?

@kmoser like how

Like: .table tr:nth-child(odd) td { background-color: red; }

the thing i want to only place values between some td, like first column values from return data   like that

@AAVEPIntl <a> tags in the first colum only would be tr td:first-child a { color: red; }. Can you be more specific?
